# Fuzzy sets in Scala

Tags: scala, math

I am trying to implement a fuzzy set according to a given pattern.

```
class FuzzySet[T](m: T => Double) {
    
      def isEmpty(implicit universe: FuzzySet.Universe[T]): Boolean =???
    
      def equalTo(that: FuzzySet[T])(implicit u: Universe[T]): Boolean = ???
    
      def contains(v: T): Double = {
        m(v)
      }
    
      def union(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] = ???
    
      def intersect(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] = ???
    
      def complement(implicit u: Universe[T]): FuzzySet[T] = ???
    }
```

And when implementing the `union` function:

```
def union(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] = {
    new FuzzySet[T](x => m(x).max(that.m(x)))
  }
```

I get an error -

```
value m is not a member of FuzzySet[T]
    new FuzzySet[T](x => m(x).max(that.m(x)))
```

I tried to do the implementation in a different way

```
def union(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] = {
    new FuzzySet[T](x => contains(x).max(that.contains(x)))
  }
```

now everything works but it gives incorrect results.

```
object FuzzySetApp extends App {

  val someNonEmptyFuzzySet = new FuzzySet[Int]({
    case 1 => 0.5
    case 2 => 0.75
    case 3 => 1
    case _ => 0.0
  })
  val EmptyFuzzySet = new FuzzySet[Int]({
    case 1 => 0.6
    case 2 => 0.7
    case 3 => 1
    case _ => 0.0
  })
  println(someNonEmptyFuzzySet.union(emptyFuzzySet).contains(1)) //prints 0.5 instead of 0.6
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, you are confusing `EmptyFuzzySet` (pascalcase) with `emptyFuzzySet` (camelcase). You did not show us how `emptyFuzzySet` is declared.

You need a `val` in front for to make that member visible

```scala
class FuzzySet[T](val m: T => Double)
```

But you should use a `case class` instead where all members are visible by default.
Also you can just rename `m` as `contains` and do away with the extra method:

```scala
case class FuzzySet[T](contains: T => Double) {
  def union(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] =
    FuzzySet(x => contains(x).max(that.contains(x)))
}

val someNonEmptyFuzzySet = FuzzySet[Int] {
  case 1 => 0.5
  case 2 => 0.75
  case 3 => 1
  case _ => 0
}

val emptyFuzzySet = FuzzySet[Int] {
  case 1 => 0.6
  case 2 => 0.7
  case 3 => 1
  case _ => 0
}

println(someNonEmptyFuzzySet.union(emptyFuzzySet).contains(1))
```

EDIT:
I also see that you are trying to implement an equality method with `equalTo`. There's no need to since `case class`es provide equational reasoning for free. The caveat is that it doesn't work for lambdas. So instead of a `T => Double` you should reimplement your mappings with a `Map[T, Double]`, together with an additional default value.

```scala
case class FuzzySet[T](m: Map[T, Double], default: Double) {
  def contains(x: T): Double = m.getOrElse(x, default)
  def union(that: FuzzySet[T]): FuzzySet[T] = FuzzySet(
    (m.keySet ++ that.m.keySet).map(k => k -> contains(k).max(that.contains(k))).toMap,
    default.max(that.default)
  )
}

val someNonEmptyFuzzySet = FuzzySet(Map(
  1 -> 0.5,
  2 -> 0.75,
  3 -> 1,
), 0)

val emptyFuzzySet = FuzzySet(Map(
  1 -> 0.6,
  2 -> 0.7,
  3 -> 1
), 0)

val unionSet1 = someNonEmptyFuzzySet.union(emptyFuzzySet)
val unionSet2 = emptyFuzzySet.union(someNonEmptyFuzzySet)

println(unionSet1.contains(1))  //0.6
println(unionSet2.contains(1))  //0.6
println(unionSet1 == unionSet2) //true - equality for free
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error is simple to fix. In the `class` declaration, `m` is not a member of the class:

```
class FuzzySet[T](m: T => Double) {
```

`m` is just a constructor parameter, and is effectively only visible within the constructor. Make it `val m` and you will be able to call it on other instances of `FuzzySet`. Or create an alias for it in a member value inside the body of the `class` if you want to control visibility.